# Cucumber using @Transform tag,how to run test multiple times for different rows and column

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-java

I am reading the test data from JSON File. I got the below data in the form of 
data table as shown below.

```
|Key         |Key         |Key         |
|Firstdataset|firstdataset|firstDataSet|    
|seconddataSet|seconddataSet|SecondDataSet|
```

now in the step definition class, I'm using the below code

```
List<Map<String,String>> data2=table.asMaps(String.class, String.class);
            System.out.println(data2);
            for(int i=0;i<data2.size();i++) {
    data2.get(i).get("ScenarioRun"));
 }
```

The `Map` has 2 test data set rows.
I want my scenario to execute twice with each row test data used one time.The for loop just display the data and not running the test scenario twice.
If I use scenario Outline how to mention the dynamic rows ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt understand your question. Would try to answer whatever I understood.
First:

```
 |Key         |Key         |Key         |
|Firstdataset|firstdataset|firstDataSet|    
|seconddataSet|seconddataSet|SecondDataSet|
```

Key is the key of your Map which cannot be duplicate. Hence the above statement should be like:

```
|Key1         |Key2         |Key3         |
    |Firstdataset|firstdataset|firstDataSet|    
    |seconddataSet|seconddataSet|SecondDataSet|
```

Second:

```
List<Map<String,String>> data2=table.asMaps(String.class, String.class);
            System.out.println(data2);
            for(int i=0;i<data2.size();i++) {
    data2.get(i).get("ScenarioRun"));
 }
```

This should be:

```
List<Map<String,String>> data2=table.asMaps(String.class, String.class);
            System.out.println(data2);
            for(int i=0;i<data2.size();i++) {
    data2.get(i).get("**Key1**"));
 }
```

As we are want to pick the value corresponding it which would be **Firstdataset** for the first iteration and **seconddataSet** for the second iteration.

For using dynamic values in the Scenario outline, you can use angular brackets in the like we do anywhere else in the feature file.
eg:

```
|Key1         |Key2         |Key3         |
|<dataset>|firstdataset|firstDataSet|    
|seconddataSet|seconddataSet|SecondDataSet|

Examples:
|dataset|
|firstdataSet|
```

Comment: First Line of My question is "I am reading the test data from JSON File. I got the below data in the form of data table as shown below."

The Data I am getting using Transform class.

I want to run the test scenario dynamically based on the number of Rows present in the MAP/DataTable.

Comment: Just to Repeat:
1. I have a feature file to execute.
2. I kept the test data in JSON File.
3.I read the data and used Transform Class to get it in the form of Datatable.
4.While fetching the data as MAP from the Datatable,I'm not able to found a way to run it more then one dataSet.

I'm using JSON for test data.

Regards,
Balwinder